# Excel VBA let user to input new sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to list all files in chosen folder. Now it creates new sheet with name "Files". How to modify this code to let user input folder name every time he clicks the button? So basically scenario would look like this:

1. Click button
2. Choose folder to List files from
3. Type new Worksheet name where files will be listed
4. Code processed
5. Click button
6. Choose folder to List files from
7. Type new Worksheet name where files will be listed
8. Code processed
9. Same actions till the end of the world

I have tried this one but probably have mistakes inputting to my code:

```
Dim NewName As String 
NewName = InputBox("What Do you Want to Name the Sheet1 ?") 
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = NewName
```

I have tried to modify this with:

```
Sheets.Add.Name = NewName
        Sheets(NewName).[A1].Resize(AllFiles.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AllFiles.keys)
```

My code for listing files and full path to each file:

```
Sub ListAllFilesInAllFolders()

    Dim MyPath As String, MyFolderName As String, MyFileName As String
    Dim i As Integer, F As Boolean
    Dim objShell As Object, objFolder As Object, AllFolders As Object, AllFiles As Object
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next

    '************************
    'Select folder
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "", 0, 0)
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        'MyPath = 
        MyPath = objFolder.self.Path & "\"
    Else
        Exit Sub

    End If
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing

    '************************
    'List all folders

    Set AllFolders = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set AllFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    AllFolders.Add (MyPath), ""
    i = 0
    Do While i < AllFolders.Count
        Key = AllFolders.keys
        MyFolderName = Dir(Key(i), vbDirectory)
        Do While MyFolderName <> ""
            If MyFolderName <> "." And MyFolderName <> ".." Then
                If (GetAttr(Key(i) & MyFolderName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                    AllFolders.Add (Key(i) & MyFolderName & "\"), ""
                End If
            End If
            MyFolderName = Dir
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    'List all files
    For Each Key In AllFolders.keys
        MyFileName = Dir(Key & "*.*")
        'MyFileName = Dir(Key & "*.PDF")    'only PDF files
        Do While MyFileName <> ""
            AllFiles.Add (Key & MyFileName), ""
            MyFileName = Dir
        Loop
    Next

    '************************
    'List all files in Files sheet

    For Each MySheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If MySheet.Name = "Files" Then
            Sheets("Files").Cells.Delete
            F = True
            Exit For
        Else
            F = False
        End If
    Next
    If Not F Then Sheets.Add.Name = "Files"

    'Sheets("Files").[A1].Resize(AllFolders.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AllFolders.keys)
    Sheets("Files").[A1].Resize(AllFiles.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AllFiles.keys)
    Set AllFolders = Nothing
    Set AllFiles = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets("Sheet1").Name = NewName    should be either Sheets("Files").Name = NewName  or Sheets(1).Name = NewName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
With Sheets.Add
    .Name = NewName
    .Range("A1").Resize(AllFiles.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AllFiles.keys)
End With
```

Also, no need to to loop to test if the sheet exists. Use Error Handling instead

```
Dim FilesSheet as Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set FilesSheet = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Files")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not FilesSheet is Nothing then
    F = True
    Set FilesSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    FilesSheet.Name = NewName
Else
    F = False
    FilesSheet.Cells.Delete
End If

FilesSheet.Range("A1").Resize(AllFiles.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AllFiles.keys)
```

If you are creating this for End Users you may also want to build in functionality to check that the `NewName` they enter isn't too long (>31 Characters) for an Excel Sheet Name and doesn't contain any illegal characters (<kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd>)

Comment: Also worth checking that the sheet name isn't already in use!